# Surface Laptop Studio running Windows 11 cannot display 4k60hz on Samsung TV

Tags: windows, hdmi, tv, intel-graphics, microsoft-surface

I have a 4k Samsung TV with a resolution of 3840x2160 which supports a refresh rate of 60 Hz.

But my Surface Laptop Studio running Windows 11 can only do 3840x2160 with 30 Hz. If I up it to 60 Hz, everything gets really blurry and choppy and graphics and text are repeated. Tried 59.94 Hz (lol ntsc) as well, same thing happened.

I have a Microsoft USB-C to HDMI adaptor hooked up to an HDMI cable hooked up to the TV. I've tried both USB-C slots on the left side of the Surface Laptop Studio and two of the HDMI slots on the TV.

See this album for reference: https://postimg.cc/gallery/14YHMpR

My Surface Book 2 and my work HP laptop, both running Windows 10, can both output 3840x2160 in 60 Hz to it. Can't remember if I had to first configure anything for the SB2 years ago, but I know I didn't do anything unusual to configure the HP laptop, it just worked. Been using this setup for a few years with the SB2.

For clarity: I am using this recommended adapter from Microsoft [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B076KRFB8X/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B076KRFB8X) (purchased in 2020) and this HDMI cable that supports HDCP 2.2 [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0761ZVQHD/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0761ZVQHD) (purchased in 2018) and I just tested the other two laptops with the same adapter, cable, and TV and they both worked fine with 4k60Hz.

My Surface Laptop Studio has a dedicated Nvidia GPU, but the usb-c slot says it is connected to the Intel Iris Xe integrated graphics card. However I'm positive this card should be able to drive 4k60Hz.

Since the Surface Laptop Studio only has these two usb-c slots for graphics and/or peripherals, my suspicion (as someone with very minimal hardware knowledge) is now that perhaps part of the data is being lost to regular USB support and therefore the bandwidth is not enough for 4k60hz. No clue how I'd resolve this but perhaps it's in the device manager.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went into the Samsung TV settings and I went into External Device Manager -> HDMI UHD Color and selected the HDMI port. For whatever reason, this seems to have fixed the issue, 4k60hz works on the Surface Laptop Studio and the other laptops continue to function correctly. Why that fixed it, I can't say! But hopefully someone else will be able to make use of this as well.